# ImportError: No module named 'deployment'

Tags: python

Not sure whether I should be posting this on askubuntu or here.
I am trying to perform object detection using Tensorflow. I am therefor following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/JR8CmWyh2E8?t=709) (this link shows the exact issue I am facing).

When running [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/train.py), I get this error:

```
$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/trainer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from deployment import model_deploy
ImportError: No module named 'deployment
```

According to the info I found online and the video I linked above I have to execute this command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/slim
```

While being in the `tensorflow/model/` directory. Yet, it doesn't solve my issue. And I don't really know what I should check in order to find out what is causing this persistent issue.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

exactly what I do:

```
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection$ cd ../../../../
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/slim
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models$ cd ~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/trainer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from deployment import model_deploy
ImportError: No module named 'deployment'
(tensorflow) xxx@yyy-ThinkPad-X200:~/Downloads/models/research/build/lib/object_detection$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
:$HOME/tensorflow-models-master/research:$HOME/tensorflow-models-master/research/slim
```

Export pythonpath should be done from `models/research` . You are doing it from `models`. So, it is taking wrong directory path.
Try running `export $PYTHONPATH` from `models/research` and it would solve the problem.